# Using default IModelBinder within custom binder in Web API 2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, model-binding

How do you call the default model binder within Web API in a custom `IModelBinder`? I know MVC has a default binder, but I can't use it with Web API. I just want to use the default Web API binder, and then run some custom logic after that (to avoid re-inventing the wheel).

```
public class CustomBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        // Get default binding (can't mix Web API and MVC)
        var defaultMvcBinder = System.Web.ModelBinding.ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder;
        var result = defaultMvcBinder.BindModel(actionContext, bindingContext); // Won't work
        if (result == false) return false;
        // ... set additional model properties
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case others stumble on this question, I had to implement the custom model binder with activation context since there is nothing to re-use from Web API. Here is the solution I am using for my limited scenarios that needed to be supported.

**Usage**

The implementation below allows me to let any model optionally use `JsonProperty` for model binding, but if not provided, will default to just the property name. It supports mappings from standard .NET types (string, int, double, etc). Not quite production ready, but it meets my use cases so far.

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(AttributeModelBinder))]
public class PersonModel
{
    [JsonProperty("pid")]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

This allows the following query string to be mapped in a request:

```
/api/endpoint?pid=1&name=test
```

**Implementation**

First, the solution defines a mapped property to track the source property of the model and the target name to use when setting the value from the value provider.

```
public class MappedProperty
{
    public MappedProperty(PropertyInfo source)
    {
        this.Info = source;
        this.Source = source.Name;
        this.Target = source.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyAttribute>()?.PropertyName ?? source.Name;
    }
    public PropertyInfo Info { get; }
    public string Source { get; }
    public string Target { get; }
}
```

Then, a custom model binder is defined to handle the mapping. It caches the reflected model properties to avoid repeating the reflection on subsequent calls. It may not be quite production ready, but initial testing has been promising.

```
public class AttributeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public static object _lock = new object();
    private static Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<MappedProperty>> _mappings = new Dictionary<Type, IEnumerable<MappedProperty>>();


    public IEnumerable<MappedProperty> GetMapping(Type type)
    {
        if (_mappings.TryGetValue(type, out var result)) return result; // Found
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_mappings.TryGetValue(type, out result)) return result; // Check again after lock
            return (_mappings[type] = type.GetProperties().Select(p => new MappedProperty(p)));
        }
    }

    public object Convert(Type target, string value)
    {
        try
        {
            var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(target);
            if (converter != null)
                return converter.ConvertFromString(value);
            else
                return target.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(target) : null;
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException)
        {
            return target.IsValueType ? Activator.CreateInstance(target) : null;
        }
    }

    public void SetValue(object model, MappedProperty p, IValueProvider valueProvider)
    {
        var value = valueProvider.GetValue(p.Target)?.AttemptedValue;
        if (value == null) return;
        p.Info.SetValue(model, this.Convert(p.Info.PropertyType, value));
    }

    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        try
        {
            var model = Activator.CreateInstance(bindingContext.ModelType);
            var mappings = this.GetMapping(bindingContext.ModelType);
            foreach (var p in mappings)
                this.SetValue(model, p, bindingContext.ValueProvider);
            bindingContext.Model = model;
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```